# Json POST request in Excel vba

Tags: json, excel, vba, xmlhttprequest, serverxmlhttp

I am trying to get trains information (date, time and prices) using the website https://www.trainline.fr/search

I would like to use Excel VBA (I am trying the POST request method via MSXML2.XMLHTT) to send a JSon request and parse the answer in a table.

I don't know which part of the right panel of

[image: IE - DevTools Screenshot] to use in my code

The request sent looks like this :

```
{"search":{"departure_date":"2018-04-01T10:00:00UTC","return_date":null,"cuis":{},"systems":["sncf","db","idtgv","ouigo","trenitalia","ntv","hkx","renfe","benerail","ocebo","westbahn","leoexpress","locomore","busbud","flixbus","distribusion","city_airport_train","obb","timetable"],"exchangeable_part":null,"source":null,"is_previous_available":false,"is_next_available":false,"departure_station_id":"4916","via_station_id":null,"arrival_station_id":"233","exchangeable_pnr_id":null,"passenger_ids":["173716784"],"card_ids":["7118357"]}}
```

I am actually using the navigate method which is very much easier but I want to progress in a more efficient and interesting method.

My actual code :

```
Dim objHTTP As Object
Dim Json As String 
Dim result As String

'here I am pulling in the request {"search":{"departure_date":"2018...
Json = Worksheets("Test").Range("A1")

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
URL = "https://www.trainline.fr/api/v5_1/search"

objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
objHTTP.send (Json)

result = objHTTP.responseText
```

Thank you for sharing your knowledge

Comment: What is the exact issue do you have with the above code?